# How to put a spy to a single function using SinonJS?

Tags: sinon, spy

I have this:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import {someFunc, someOtherFunc} from 'someModule';

describe("Something", () => {

  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

  beforeEach('setup sandbox', function() {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach('restore sandbox', function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("SomeTest", async () => {

    const spy = sanbox.spy(someFunc);
    someOtherFunc(1);
    console.log(spy.callCount) // prints 0
    
  })
```

someFunc() is just a simple function, it is exported like:

```
export function someFunc(...)
```

It is called by someOtherFunc(). Yet, the spy never gets called. The number of calls is 0.

Is it not possible to use Sinon this way? This works fine with Jest.

I think it's not working because sinon doesn't replace the function with the spy.

I also tried to put a spy to the module itself:

```
import * as lib from 'someModule'
...


 it("SomeTest", async () => {

    const spy = sanbox.spy(lib);
    lib.someOtherFunc(1);
    console.log(spy.someFunc.callCount) // prints 0

  })
```

But this produces the same results. 0 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write spy on object methods. You can probably import whole object and write a spy for the function using object.

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import someModule from 'someModule';

describe("Something", () => {

      let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

      beforeEach('setup sandbox', function() {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      });

      afterEach('restore sandbox', function() {
        sandbox.restore();
      });

      it("SomeTest", async() => {

        const spy = sanbox.spy(someModule, 'someFunc');
        someModule.someOtherFunc(1);
        console.log(spy.callCount) // prints 0

      })
```

Comment: Thx. Tried this now, still prints 0. I guess that's because this is a module exporting standalone functions. So it's not a class or object with methods, these are just functions. 
Must I export something like export default { someMethod:(){}, someOtherMethod(){} } to make this work??

Comment: yes, I think you  to export and use someMethod using a reference like this.someMethod inside it.

Comment: Confirmed. Sinon syp only works with objects and classes (probably). Does not work with standalone functions and lambas.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify:

In order to be able to use Sinon spies, you need to export your module functionality in a certain way. Basically, use classes or objects.

Works:

```
export default {
func() {},
func2() {}
}

export const someLib {
func() {},
func2() {}
}

module.exports = {
func() {}
}

class Ping {
func() {}
}

export default Ping();
```

or something similar.

What doesn't work:

```
export function func() {}
export function func2  {}

export const foo = () => {}
```

and so on..